# ¿Cómo puedo decir apropiadamente en inglés "espero que se encuentre bien"?

Tags: traducción

Necesito mandar un email en inglés pero necesito saber cómo puedo decir de una forma más profesional "Espero que se encuentre bien".

Ya traté:

> I hope you are ok

pero eso no me parece muy profesional.

Comment: Normalmente yo use "I hope this email finds you well". Lo podría como respuesta, pero no sé hasta qué punto esta web está para traducir al inglés. Se puede preguntar por el significado en inglés de algo, pero no sé si las traducciones del español al inglés son realmente on-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs at ELL.

Answer (score 2):

Depende de la persona a la que les escribas. Lo que has traducido esta bien, sólo que en vez de OK diría fine o well.

> I hope you are fine.
>
> I hope you are well.

Sin embargo, si es un tema de salud podrías decir **I hope you are feeling alright/well/better**

Si la carta será dirigida a alguien y que cuando la reciba esté bien en todo aspecto puedes decir **I hope this email finds you in good health**

Pero en realidad en Norte América (Canadá/USA) no hay mucha introducción, pues les gusta ir al grano y no son como los hispanos que nos gusta parafrasear cartas o correos.

Yo creo que podrías empezar **I'm writing you this letter in reply to your letter... blah blah**, si es en respuesta a una carta/correo previa(o)

O simplemente **I'm writing you this ...[give reasons=dar razones]**

Y para terminar tu carta o correo

**Sincerely** o **Sincerely yours** o **Best regards**. Este último es un poco menos formal

Answer (score 1):

> I hope this finds you well

or

> I hope this message finds you well

Eso es la traducción literal también.  Y también se lo usa en ambientes profesionales escritos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar:

> I hope you are well
>
> Best regards

o simplemente

> Sincerely